# Sabre Profile Search - using EPS_ProfileSearchService to gather all Traveler Profiles Associated with a Given Corporate Profile

Tags: c#, soap, sabre

I'm trying to gather a list of all of the TPA identity data for travelers associated (TVL) with a given Company level association (CRP) in Sabre Profiles. While I am able to pull back all TPA Identities for a given PCC, I cannot get the service to return any results when applying the association filter. My Request is below (with some identifying data redacted) - am I using the wrong search qualifier or something?

For the given company in question, I know that there are 17 Traveler Level Profiles associated with the company name I'm passing in as I can see them in Sabre Red.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="6.46" ReturnPaymentCardToken="Y">
  <ProfileSearchCriteria ProfileNameOnly="Y" PageNumber="1" ReturnCount="250" xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas">
    <TPA_Identity ProfileTypeCode="TVL" ClientCode="TN" ClientContextCode="TMP" ProfileName="*" DomainID="PCC1" />
    <CustomerReferenceInfo />
    <AssociatedProfiles AssocProfileName="Corporate Company Name" DomainID="PCC1" />
  </ProfileSearchCriteria>
</Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRQ>
```

Response:

```
<Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" TimeStamp="2018-12-24T20:16:07.809Z" Version="6.49">
<ResponseMessage xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas">
<Success/>
</ResponseMessage>
<ProfileInfo xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas">
<Message>
No profiles are found which match your selection criteria
</Message>
</ProfileInfo>
</Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRS>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had my question all written out but then I figured out the correct fields to apply to filter this properly, so I figured I'd answer this one for anyone else that might find it helpful.

The functional XML RQ is below. I believe the `CustomerReferenceInfo` piece can be omitted, but I left it in there since this did return the results I wanted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="6.46" ReturnPaymentCardToken="Y">
  <ProfileSearchCriteria ProfileNameOnly="Y" PageNumber="1" ReturnCount="250" xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas">
    <TPA_Identity ProfileTypeCode="TVL" ClientCode="TN" ClientContextCode="TMP" ProfileName="*" DomainID="PCC1" />
    <CustomerReferenceInfo />
    <AssociatedProfiles AssocProfileName="CompanyProfileName" DomainID="PCC1" IncludeTemplateAssoc="Y" />
  </ProfileSearchCriteria>
</Sabre_OTA_ProfileSearchRQ>
```